# Prove that every planar graph is the union of at most $5$ acyclic graphs.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> Prove that every planar graph is the union of at most $5$ acyclic
>   graphs.
>
> *Reminder: As union of two graphs $G_1(V_1, E_1)$ and $G_2(V_2, E_2)$ we consider the graph $G(V_1\cup V_2,E_1\cup E_2)$*

I have tried induction on the number of vertices, but I seem to miss something

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried induction on the number of vertices, but I seem to miss something.

Comment: Does every planar graph have a vertex of degree $\le5$?

Comment: Yes, that's true. Hmm I think I know what you are trying to say. Do you suggest that I connect somehow the 5 acyclic subgraphs to the vertex of degree ≤ 5?